# Solve the following equation: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2y}{x}+\cos(y/x^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Solve the following equation:
>   $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2y}{x}+\cos(y/x^2)$$

Well, I tried to separate the variables $x$ and $y$ in each side but I couldn't!
Also, I tried to find an integrating factor that the equation be exact but that was worthless, can someone help by giving a hint or solution?

Answer (score 1):

$y = x^2 u\\
y' = 2xu + x^2 u'\\
2xu + x^2 u' = 2xu + \cos u\\
(\sec u) u' = \frac 1{x^2}\\
\ln{\sec u + \tan u} = - \frac 1{x}+C\\
\sec \frac {y}{x^2} + \tan \frac {y}{x^2} = Ce^{-\frac 1x}\\ 
$

I am not seeing much farther to take this.

Comment: $$
\sec^2 u - \tan^2 u = 1 \iff (\sec u  - \tan u)(\sec u + \tan u) = 1
$$
so we have
$$
\sec u  - \tan u = \frac{1}{C}\mathrm{e}^{1/x}\\
\sec u + \tan u = C\mathrm{e}^{-1/x}
$$
or
$$
2\sec u = C\mathrm{e}^{-1/x} + \frac{1}{C}\mathrm{e}^{1/x} 
$$
This becomes
$$
u = \frac{y}{x^2} = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2\left(C\mathrm{e}^{-1/x} + \frac{1}{C}\mathrm{e}^{1/x}\right) }\right)
$$
or
$$
y = x^2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2\left(C\mathrm{e}^{-1/x} + \frac{1}{C}\mathrm{e}^{1/x}\right) }\right)
$$